# convert character month to integer in R by data table with missing rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column month which was import as a char type within a data.table, for instant "January" "March" etc. In this column also contain some missing data *NA*.

I am using the below code to convert it to integer month:

```
dt <- dt[!is.na(month), month := match(month, month.abb)]
```

I got warning in console:

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`dt, !is.na(month), `:=`(month,  :
  Coerced integer RHS to character to match the type of the target column (column 9 named 'month'). If the target column's type character is correct, it's best for efficiency to avoid the coercion and create the RHS as type character. To achieve that consider R's type postfix: typeof(0L) vs typeof(0), and typeof(NA) vs typeof(NA_integer_) vs typeof(NA_real_). You can wrap the RHS with as.character() to avoid this warning, but that will still perform the coercion. If the target column's type is not correct, it's best to revisit where the DT was created and fix the column type there; e.g., by using colClasses= in fread(). Otherwise, you can change the column type now by plonking a new column (of the desired type) over the top of it; e.g. DT[, `month`:=as.integer(`month`)]. If the RHS of := has nrow(DT) elements then the assignment is called a column plonk and is the way to change a column's type. Column types can be observed with sapply(DT,typeof).
```

Also, the value of month column became *NA* . Any idea? thank you very much.

table look like

```
month    |year  |
September| 1987 |
March    | 1999 |
```

Expect change to :

```
month    |year  |
  9      | 1987 |
  3      | 1999 |
```

Final change and work:

```
dt[!is.na(month), month := match(month, month.name)]
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I think the issue is with updating the type.  your original column seems to be character and now you are replacing with integer `match`.  May be you could create a new column

Answer (score 1):

Removing is.na should work by converting the whole column into integer class and match returns NA when not found:

```
dt[, month := match(month, month.abb)]
```

I think the jargon is plonking when updating by reference

Comment: Thanks for reply, I change it to dt <- dt[!is.na(month), month := match(month, month.name) and it work. Even still got the warning. And the previous one not work is I use 'month.abb' which is for the shortcut of Month like 'Jan' 'Sep', but after change it to 'month.name', the convert is work fine. Thank you